# Can I use a site's ip to hide my ip?

Tags: networking

I was thinking that is it possible to use a site's ip to hide mine?
Somthing like that I'm searching on bing, but my isp just think that I'm using google. (Just like google is my vpn server)

Comment: This doesn't make total sense. If you want to hide your IP use a proxy or a VPN service.

Comment: So is the question more about hiding your own IP from Bing, or about hiding Bing's IP from your ISP?

Comment: Hiding my ip from isp

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. Acting as a VPN server or a proxy server and relaying requests is something that needs to be specifically enabled and/or installed – that functionality just isn't there by default.

There are *some* web sites which allow this, either by design or by accident (e.g. Google Translate allows translating webpages by URL and will download that webpage through Google's own network).

But it's rare as such functionality can be easily abused, e.g. tricking a webserver into downloading an internal corporate network URL can bypass the firewalls, and downloading large files through someone's personal web server can result in massive bills for the owner.

Comment: +1, although I would've also stated that this limits the traffic to webserving only. You cannot, for example stream netflix or torrent using this method at all.